# What's going wrong with my attempt to install/upgrade Node.JS in Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, upgrade, node.js

OS: Linux Mint 18.3. Similar to Ubuntu.

As ever with Linux I don't really know how I'm meant to go about installing software:

1. is it already on the system? In this case yes, but it's very old: 4.2.6. The current LTS version at time of writing is 10.16.3.
2. should I use apt?
3. should I use Software Manager?
4. should I use a PPA?
5. should I download a compressed file and extract?

Sofware Manager comments from other users are things like "go here for the latest version" (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions)

The very first command there is

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

This fails:

```
> 
mike@M17A ~ $  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
[sudo] password for mike: 

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]       
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]     

... // then many messages like this:

Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:43 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:44 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:44 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Fetched 329 kB in 23s (14.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

... I'm not sure what all those mariadb commands are all about. I have MariaDB on my system and am worried that something there is the problem.

NB attempting the next command seems to indicate that this has failed:

```
mike@M17A ~ $  sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 600 not to upgrade.
```

... i.e. the system still believes 4.2.6 is the latest version.

More generally, what precisely is the protocol for installing new software in Linux: is the above numbered list, 1 to 5, the right methodology? Using what order of priority for the method do experts install new software?

***What I then tried***

It seemed that failing `sudo apt-get update` was at the root of the problem.

Inspired by other questions I tried this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

followed by this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

More lists of errors and warnings that don't mean much to me:

```
...
Err:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:41 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:43 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:44 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Fetched 329 kB in 28s (11.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

***Later I tried the "manual installation" at the github page...***
Failed in the same way:

```
mike@M17A ~ $  VERSION=node_10.16.3
mike@M17A ~ $  DISTRO="$(lsb_release -s -c)"
mike@M17A ~ $  echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.16.3 sylvia main
mike@M17A ~ $  echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.16.3 sylvia main
mike@M17A ~ $  sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
...

Ign:57 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free Translation-en
Err:58 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free amd64 Packages
  503  Backend unavailable, connection timeout
Ign:59 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free i386 Packages
Fetched 3,316 B in 34s (95 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x sylvia Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
W: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x/dists/sylvia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Backend unavailable, connection timeout
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I noticed that the link you provided attaches the anchor to the wrong place. The manual installation start with something like "if you are not fan of bash ...| curl". Could you try the instructions provided there?

Comment: re downvote: I am not exactly a Linux newb, but as a very low intermediate user I'm struggling with aspects of Linux in complete isolation. I simply haven't a clue what is wrong here. Please explain why you down voted if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it. In the end I found I had to tweak an installation script.

Specifically this came from [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-linux-mint/comment-page-2/#comments). However, instead of executing the CURL command I downloaded the script from that URL and commented out the two lines with "apt-get update" ... then named the file and made it executable and ran it.

Then I went

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then I went

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

The reason was that `apt-get update` is currently returning with errors on my system, and it *appears* that this killed off the script before it had set up the PPA in the source list (is this the right term?). I may be wrong about this. I am a low-level Linux person.

NB a script appears to be necessary, not least I noticed that there was a section where the file "translated" the "Linux Mint"-"sylvia" found from my system to "Ubuntu"-"xenial". Indeed, at the download site,  the URL ".../Linux Mint/sylvia/..." is non-existent, and returns a 404.

Answer (score 3):

When you are installing `node.js` using `sudo apt install nodejs` you are getting a version, which is tested for being stable within your Linux distribution. This also means that you get a pretty outdated version of the software and that some packages will just refuse to work with it. For example, the current version of `Rocket.Chat` requires `node.js >= 12`, and on my `Ubuntu 20.04` the official version is something like 10.x. At the time that you were writing your question, it probably was pretty new and that is why you were using a command

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

which executes a script, which installs the version `node.js-10.x`.

As far as I can see, the problem the script complains about is that it cannot find public keys for some of repositories which it is using. Very often the problem with keys is that due to some strange settings for `root` user, permissions for key-files turn out to be wrong.

The solution is to check permissions in directories

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
$ ls -l /usr/share/keyrings/
```

They should look like this (`-rw-r--r--` is permission `644`)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2206 Aug 25 00:40 nodesource.gpg
```

If the output for some files is different, change it manually

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
```